# neo4j finding all paths that meets a certain criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to model a graph to solve some connection time problem. So for example I have the following graph

```
    F1,F2     F3     F4
```

ST_B--------->ST2----->ST3------>ST_E

```
   F5,F6      F7       F8
```

ST_B-------->ST4---->ST5------>ST_E

```
    F9
```

ST_B-------->ST_E

I model ST_B, ST2,ST3,ST4,ST5, ST_E as station (node). and F1-F9 as flt node. And each flt node has a departure time and arrival time. And the relationship is connect. Also in this case, let's assume F2 arrival time is 30mins less than F3 departure time, and F6 is 30mins less than F7. (means the connection is not valid) So the valid route from ST_B to ST_E should be F1-F3-F4, F5-F7-F8 and F9. I have try to use cypher to solve this problem without success. (may be I am modeling it wrong).

Comment: Can you explain your domain more. No one will have any idea what ST, F1 etc means here. Next, setup your test data in console.neo4j.org and "Share" the link here (Click on the share button on the top right corner)

Comment: here is the link to the console http://console.neo4j.org/r/vxdbod, the domain consist of station (ST_B, ST2, ST? etc) and flight (F1-F9), Flight connects the station. I want to find all the valid route btw ST_B and ST_E.

Comment: here is the connect link http://console.neo4j.org/?id=l7nji7

Comment: why is the connection is not valid for F2?

Comment: F2 arrival time is 1100 (11:00am) more than F3 departure time(10:30am), same with F6 and F7.

Comment: In your post you mentioned it in reverse: let's assume F2 arrival time is 30mins less than F3 departure time, and F6 is 30mins less than F7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added labels for the nodes to distinguish flights and stations. All flights F1-F9 are labeled with :Flight, all stations ST_B, ST_E and ST_2-ST_5 are labeled with :Station.

```
Match path=stb:Station-[:Connect*]->ste:Station
Where stb.name='ST_B' and ste.name='ST_E'
With filter(x in nodes(path) where x:Flight ) as flts
Where all ( i in Range(0,length(flts)-2) Where flts[i].arrvTime < flts[i+1].dptrTime)
Return extract(flt in flts | flt.name)
```

1. The "Match" and "Where" clause retrieve all paths from ST_B to ST_E;
2. The "With" clause retrieve all flight nodes on the paths and pass them to the next "Where" clause.
3. The next "Where" clause checks the arrival time of each flight and the departure time of the connected flight to return only the valid flight combinations.
4. The final "Return" clause returns the names of flights that form a valid route.

Comment: wow, now I see the power of cypher. I have a more complicate problem that I will try to expand on this one. Will post it if I can't solve it my self.

Comment: @Lisa +1. Can you explain why you are subtracting the length(flts) with 2 rather than 1?

Comment: @Pangea. The index range of a collection is 0 to length-1, since I use 'i' and 'i+1' as indexes to access two consecutive flights, and to keep the indexes within the scope of 0~(length-1),  it must be satisfied that (i+1) <= length-1, hence i <= length -2.

Comment: I have add the Flight that use certain aircraft (some has wifi, some doesn't) and if I need to filter further down to only seeing the valid route that has wifi, what is the cypher query. Let me know if the model is wrong. Here is the link http://console.neo4j.org/r/sdcixy to the extended sample data. the correct return should be only F5-F7-F8 and F9 since F1 use AC1 which doesn't have wifi the route F1-F3-F4 is gone.

Comment: This is one of the cases I found difficult to accomplish with Cypher. It comes down to the problem of selecting a path whose nodes need to further match another pattern (flt-[:Use]->ac:Aircraft), and that pattern requires a new identifier "ac" to specify a constraint on a property such as "ac.wifi=1". This is not doable with Cypher due to the limitation that no new identifier can be introduced in the "Where" expression.

Comment: On the other hand, it seems to me it is quite reasonable to represent the "wifi" as a property of "Flight" node instead of introducing a relationship to the node "Aircraft". That would greatly simplify your query. All you need is to add another condition in the where expression "flts[i].wifi = 1".

Comment: @Lisa. I initially is thinking adding wifi to the flights. the reason why I want it separate, is the same aircraft will be used by multiple flights (of course in different departure date/time and/or stations). Also aircraft will have some of its own properties that I didn't list here. If I include wifi and some other AC properties, I am not sure whether it is the right thing to do. Do you think whether cypher in the future will support something like that?

Comment: @dbspace. I have no idea about the development of cypher. I think this is a general use case and worth further investigation. I suggest you start a new thread to draw people's attention and see if they can come up with some other solutions or helpful comments.

Comment: @Lisa. I have create a new thread as suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983857/neo4j-cypher-selecting-a-path-whose-nodes-need-to-further-match-another-pattern. Hopefully there will be some innovated solution or suggestions.

Comment: @dbspace. the other solution is to implement this with Neo4j Traversal framework. I think it's doable with a customized TraversalDescription.