# neo4j cypher selecting a path whose nodes need to further match another pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a domain that contains flight, station and aircraft. The station are connected by flight and flight use aircraft. (this is an expansion of the problem that I have on [neo4j finding all paths that meets a certain criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923027/neo4j-finding-all-paths-that-meets-a-certain-criteria))  I want to find all the valid routes that meets the connection time requirement but also use aircraft that has wifi.  I have create some sample data in the neo4j console. Here is the link [console.neo4j.org/r/sdcixy](http://console.neo4j.org/r/sdcixy).  Any suggestion will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to get paths with all flight nodes connected to Aircraft nodes with the property "wifi" equal 1. This step is implemented by the clauses 1-4. 
The clause 5 passes the  flight nodes on the qualified paths to the next "Where"
The clause 6 filter out those routes whose connections do not satisfy the condition. 
The last clause returns flight names on the valid routes.

```
1. Match p=stb:Station-[:Connect*]->flt:Flight-[:Connect*]->ste:Station, flt-[:Use]->ac:Aircraft
2. Where stb.name='ST_B' and ste.name='ST_E'
3. distinct p as path, collect(ac) as acs
4. Where all ( ac in acs where ac.wifi = 1)
5. With filter(x in nodes(path) where x:Flight ) as flts
6. Where all ( i in Range(0,length(flts)-2) Where flts[i].arrvTime < flts[i+1].dptrTime)
7. Return extract(flt in flts | flt.name)
```

Comment: in Where all ( i in Range(0,length(flts)-2) Where flts[i].arrvTime < flts[i+1].dptrTime and flts[i].name in fltnames). Should this be changed to Where all ( i in Range(0,length(flts)-2) Where flts[i].arrvTime < flts[i+1].dptrTime and all (j in range(0,length(flts)-1) where flts[j].name in fltnames) to take care of the last flt in the list.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the index "i" in the first "all" doesn't cover the last element in the collection, and actually for the second "all" the index is not necessary, all (flt in flts where flt.name in fltnames) is good enough. I updated the answer to incorporate your comment.

Comment: this is the good solution that you come up. yes I wish that the syntax will be a lot better. (if cypher allow match inside filter or all, probably make the syntax more readable.

Comment: @dbspace. I found a better solution and updated the query. The trick is to group the ac nodes by the path so that we can select paths whose flight nodes all connected to ac nodes with "wifi = 1". Now I wouldn't say the solution "awful" anymore.:-)

Comment: The query takes forever to run with 5000 station, and 4000 flights.