# neo4j and cypher - process nodes in order based on a property value

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `spring-data-neo4j` and I encountered a problem when writing one specific query with Cypher.

In my domain model I have something like this(I left out everything that is not needed)

```
@NodeEntity
class Foo extends{
    @GraphId
    val id: java.lang.Long

    @RelatedTo
    private val bars = new java.util.HashSet[Bar]() 
}

@NodeEntity
class Bar{
    @GraphId
    val id: java.lang.Long  

    @GraphProperty(propertyType = long.class)
    val departureDateTime: DateTime
    @GraphProperty(propertyType = long.class)
    val arrivalDateTime: DateTime

    val departureCity: String

    val arrivalCity: String
}
```

My query must check continuity of `bars` in `Foo` instance, meaning that for each two consecutive `bars` `bar1.arrivalCity` == `bar2.departureCity`. I need to check them in order based on their dates.

I am wondering if it is possible to write such query, or I don't have any other way then use java API.

Comment: Out of curiosity, shouldn't you have `@GraphProperty(propertyType = long.class)` as an annotation to every `DateTime` field ? In this way DateTime will be stored as a long field and it will be easy to compare.

Comment: In my normal code I have it, I will add it not to confuse anyone else. The thing is that I don't know that even if `bar1.time < bar2.time` there does not exists bar3 that has property `bar1.time < bar3.time < bar2.time`

Comment: There are some other posts related to this topic (routing of flights) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923027/neo4j-finding-all-paths-that-meets-a-certain-criteria/18928540#18928540 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983857/neo4j-cypher-selecting-a-path-whose-nodes-need-to-further-match-another-pattern