# Cypher: find a path that satisfies a condition between steps i and i+1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a cypher query which returns a path with the condition that each step must have a timestamp property with a value less than or equal to the previous step. The following is what I have so far.

```
Match path=(a:NODE)-[:PARENT*]->(b:NODE)
WHERE a.name='SOME_VALUE' and b.name='SOME_OTHER_VALUE'
WITH path, relationships(path) as steps
WHERE ALL ( i in Range(0, length(steps) - 1) WHERE steps[i].timestamp <= steps[i+1].timestamp)
RETURN path
```

I think what I have is close however the neo4j web console is telling me that I have a syntax error.

```
Invalid input '.': expected whitespace, '[', "=~", IN, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR or ')' (line 4, column 60)
"WHERE ALL ( i in Range(0, length(steps) - 1) WHERE steps[i].timestamp <= steps[i+1].timestamp)"
                                                            ^
```

I have seen properties of a relationship collection accessed this way on another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923027/neo4j-finding-all-paths-that-meets-a-certain-criteria) so I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close with your statement. You need to wrap `steps[i]` into parenthesis:

```
Match path=(a:NODE)-[:PARENT*]->(b:NODE)
WHERE a.name='SOME_VALUE' and b.name='SOME_OTHER_VALUE'
WITH path, relationships(path) as steps
WHERE ALL ( i in Range(0, length(steps) - 1) WHERE (steps[i]).timestamp <=     (steps[i+1]).timestamp)
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't try that.